# Iterate a yaml array with ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I applied `YAML.load_file` to my example file:

```
---
languages:
  - name: "English"
    iso_639: "en"
    native_name: "English"
    region:
      - ''
      - UK
      - US
  - name: "Klingon"
    iso_639: "tlh"
    native_name: "tlhIngan Hol"
    region:
      - notearth
```

I want to iterate though these languages and the region arrays. This doesn't work:

```
records.each do |record|
  record.region.each do |region|
    self.create!
  end
end
```

`record.region` gives me an unknown method error for region. How can I iterate though the languages and and their regions? Or, how can I access the region array?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "this doesn't work"? You get an error? The result you get is not what you expect?

Comment: I edited my question so minimize the actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1. The object you get after loading the YAML file is not an array, it's a hash, say the file is called `foo.yml`:

   ```
   YAML.load_file('foo.yml')
   # => {"languages"=>[{"name"=>"English", "iso_639"=>"en", ...
   ```

   Thus you have to modify your code like the following to make it work:

   ```
   records['languages'].each do |record|
     # ...
   ```
2. `region` is not a method of the hash `record`, it is a key, you have to access the related value using `record['region']`.

The correct code you have to use is:

```
records['languages'].each do |record|
  record['region'].each do |region|
    # My guess is you are going to use `region` inside this block
    self.create!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Yaml is loaded into a hash, hence it will be in form:

```
languages: [
{
  name: "English"
  iso_639: "en"
  native_name: "English"
  region: ['', 'UK', 'US']
}
{
  name: "Klingon"
  iso_639: "tlh"
  native_name: "tlhIngan Hol"
  region: ['notearth']
}]
```

So you need to iterate like:

```
results = YAML.load_file(file)
results['languages'].flat_map{|l| l['region']}.each do |region|
  self.create!
end
```

Comment: Is #symbolize_keys a Rails extension?

Comment: @WayneConrad yes it is

Comment: Thanks.  I mention it because the OP didn't tag the question with Rails.  Of course, most of the Ruby question really _are_ about Rails.

Comment: @WayneConrad - it is. I assumed this is for rails app (because of `self.create!`. If it is not, it is fine not to use it and use strings. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @BroiSatse Oh, good catch.  I missed the implication of the call to self.create!

Comment: I suggest to use `flat_map{...}` instead of `map{...}.flatten`.

Comment: hey there quick headsup... decided for the record['array'] because of prettier code and since I had to access also the other entries it was the nicer solution. And yes its a rails backend only system.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONFIG = YAML.load_file("file.yml")
puts CONFIG # {"languages"=>[{"name"=>"English", "iso_639"=>"en", "native_name"=>"English", "region"=>["", "UK", "US"]}, {"name"=>"Klingon", "iso_639"=>"tlh", "native_name"=>"tlhIngan Hol", "region"=>["notearth"]}]}

CONFIG['languages'].map{|l| l['region']}
```