# Read values under duplicate key in YAML

Tags: ruby, hash

In the following yaml file, how do I read all items under first `Sweet_fruits` and then subsequently items under second `Sweet_fruits` using some kind of loop?

```
Fruits:
  Sweet_fruits:
   apple: 1
   banana: 4
   pineapple: 10
  Sweet_fruits:
   apple: 3
   banana: 5
   mango: 6
```

Comment: You can't. It doesn't make sense. Your YAML file is equivalent, if valid, to one that only has the second instance of `Sweet_fruits`.

Comment: Why did you think your question is related to rspec?

Comment: Sure you can but should you, probably not.

Comment: @sawa you are right. completely not related to Rspec

Comment: It does make sense. Maybe I don't need a map, maybe I need YAML because it is an easily readable data structure format, and I want duplicate keys. Or are there any other data structure formats that are as easily readable that I could use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you get all the `Sweet_fruits` items in an array. You first declare items_array as an empty array variable then iterate over `Sweet_fruits`.

```
items_array = []
 Fruits['Sweet_fruits'].each do |items|
   items_array << items
 end
```

Answer (score 4):

Your YAML is illegal per the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044) ("The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is **unique**.") You could do this instead:

```
Fruits:
  - Sweet_fruits:
     apple: 1
     banana: 4
     pineapple: 10
  - Sweet_fruits:
     apple: 3
     banana: 5
     mango: 6
```

and iterate over the array under `Fruits`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me how to iterate over the array under Fruits?

Comment: @Chuchoo Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350738/iterate-a-yaml-array-with-ruby